# Migrate all email messages into a SharePoint Lists

Tags: 2007, email

I need to migrate all email messages into a SharePoint Lists.Can any give me guide to do it. or is their any built in list which will support emailing format and attachment ?

Thanks
Shiva Reddy.P

Comment: Are you looking at syncing outlook to a Sharepoint List?

Comment: not really we are getting email message information from eRoom Server.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of articles that may help:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bgeorgi/configuring-email-enabled-lists)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621010410/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joelo/archive/2007/10/23/email-enabled-lists-and-inbound-email.aspx)